# Unable to show page in iframe in Ektron CMS

Tags: ektron

I am working on Ektron 8.6.0.060 CMS, on admin dashboard I add an custom widget in which I call an iframe for content page, on picking URL from iframe, 404 page not found error occurs. All URL and signs are using correctly still error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are entering a fully qualified domain name in your IFrame. Unless you are very careful about your paths, relative locations will likely be incorrect. Rather than "/page/item.aspx" or "www.site.com/page/item.aspx" make sure you include your protocol, e.g. "http://www.site.com/page/item.aspx" . This is particularly easy to forget if you are generating this url dynamically.

Also, if you are pointing to ektron content, make sure the content is published and public.